# How do I prove this set of elements of a $\sigma$-algebra is independent?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

For some fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $X = [0,1)$ with the $\sigma$-algebra $M$ generated by the collection of intervals

$$
\left\{
\left[\frac{j-1}{2^N}, \frac{j}{2^N}\right)
      : j \in \left\{1,2,...,2^N\right\}
\right\}
$$
with measure
$$
\mu\left(\left[\frac{j-1}{2^N}, \frac{j}{2^N}\right)\right)
 = 2^{-N}, \quad \forall j \in \left\{1,2,..,2^N\right\}
$$

We define the sets:

$$
E_k := \bigg\{x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{2^i} \in[0,1):a_k = 1, a_i \in\{0,1\} \text{ for } i\in\mathbb{N}-\{k\} \text{  and infinitely many } a_i \text{ are 0}\bigg\}
$$

Prove that $\{E_1, E_2, ..., E_N, \emptyset, X\}$ is independent and that there is no independent family of more than $N+2$ members.

Now, as an example, I fixed $N=4$ and obtained the following sets:

$$E_1 = \{1/2\}$$
$$E_2 = \{1/4, 3/4\}$$
$$E_3 = \{1/8, 3/8, 5/8, 7/8\}$$
$$E_4 = \{1/16, 3/16, 5/16, 7/16, 9/16, 11/16, 13/16, 15/16\}$$

Which made me conclude that, for any fixed $N$

$$E_k = \left\{\frac{2i-1}{2^k}:1\leq i \leq N\right\}$$

I need to prove the following

$$
\mu\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^k A_j\right)
 = \prod_{j=1}^k \mu(A_j)$$ for each $k$-tuple $A_1, ..., A_k \in M
$

If I got it right with the interpretation, I am confused on how to proceed. Nevertheless, I am suspicious of my interpretation of the problem because $E_i \cap E_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$

Do I have to use the intervals using the elements of $E_k$ as boundaries? e.g. for $E_2$ I'd have the interval $[1/4, 3/4)$ and for $E_3$ I'd have $[1/8,3/8), [3/8, 5/8), [5/8, 7/8)$?

How can I prove that there can be at most $N+2$ in any independent family of sets?

Comment: In your definition it follows that all $E_k$ are infinite sets..

Comment: No because $a_{i>k} = 0$

Comment: That's not what the definition says: there are infinitely many $a_i =0$ so there could be infinitely many $i$ with $a_i=1$ too (odd vs even e.g.)

Comment: Why? What I got from the definition was that for $i < k$, $a_i$ could be $0$ or $1$; for $i = k$, $a_i = a_k = 1$ and for $i>k$, $a_i = 0$ you are adding the $a_i/2^i$ to get the $x$ values

Comment: If you mean that for all $i >k$ we must have $a_i=0$ then you have finite sets.

Comment: I am not sure which option it is. I am confused because that is how the problem was worded

Comment: Now your definition says literally "infinitely many $a_i$ are $0$" which is weaker. Is this wording literally the one in your problem?

Comment: The ones for $i > k$? I still don't see the problem. But, how can I progress? I'm stuck. This is literally the wording. I know it is bad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89124/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-henno-brandsma).